# localhost/phpmyadmin / erro 1146

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou com um problema ao acessar o phpmyadmin. Segue o erro ->  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já conferiu a configuração do banco de dados?

Comment: Esse erro ao que tudo parece é que você está definindo um tipo de charset que o banco não reconhece, e por ele não encontrar nenhuma referência, ele retorna o erro.

Comment: teste converter o padrão para: `skip-character-set-client-handshake=1` e
`default-character-set=utf8`

Comment: Muito provavelmente a sua `collation` do banco e tabela estão diferentes